# How to join two SQL tables with same columns name with different ids in one single row?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id location    code
1  Bangalore   BN
2  Chennai     CH
3  Kochi       KH

slno first_loc Second_loc
1       1        2
3       3        1
```

How to join this two tables in MySQL

Comment: what is your output

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried and what errors you are getting. Also please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the output you want?

Answer (score 1):

Just use an alias, I assume your first table named `location`, the second table named `route` since you don't give the tables' name

```
Select slno, a.location, b.location from route
   left join location as a on route.first_loc = a.id
   left join location as b on route.second_loc = b.id
```